# How do we call javascript from a codeigniter controller method

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, redirect

I have a controller "track" in codeigniter where I have many methods. In one of the methods I am just redirecting user to some other URL which comes from url parameter as

```
track.php

function click_thru()
{
  redirect($this->uri->segment(3));
}
```

Before Redirection I want to call google tracker Javascript code. As I am not loading any view in the above method, how do I call JS before redirect?

Comment: It's not enough clear. Please give more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, PHP and Javascript don't communicate each other like this, you have two solutions :

- Either finding a way to do your redirection in javascript after the google tracker call is called (but you have to load the entire body of the response just for one redirection, so not very cool).
- Either you find a PHP API that permits you to interact with Google Analytics. Like this one : https://code.google.com/p/php-ga/

Comment: I am already using the first option which is not good and I am loading the view just for redirection. I will check with other option you suggested thanks